# Why does WebRequest only work twice?

Tags: httpwebrequest

I have a very simple HTTP get application, and here is an even simpler redacted version of it

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace UploadRichardsStatusConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            const string requestString = "http://www.google.com/";
            while (true)
            {
                var request = WebRequest.Create(requestString);
                Console.WriteLine("request sent = " + requestString);
                try
                {
                    var response = request.GetResponse();
                    Console.WriteLine("response.ContentLength = " + response.ContentLength);
                }
                catch (WebException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Request timed out");
                }
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The real console app has my own Azure URL, but the problem manifests itself whatever the request string, even with Google, so I do not think this is a server side issue. When I run the code the first two loops succeed, i.e. the `response.ContentLength` is reported. Thereafter they timeout. Why do I only get two calls? The actual app I'm working on uses an HTTP GET to periodically report status and so I need to do this repeatedly (more than twice!)

I should note that I have tried:

- adding an unused query attribute onto the URL so that each URL is
  distinct
- setting the timeout to huge values
- bypassing the cache

but none of these worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not disposing of the response, which means it's still tying up the connection pool for that host. Subsequent requests for the same host will wait for the connection to be freed up, which means waiting for a garbage collection / finalizer round which may never happen.

Use a `using` statement and it should be fine:

```
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: That works - thanks Jon (I'll accept as answer in a few minutes when I can).